# Custom list adapter and different layouts for vertical/horizontal orientation

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Something that puzzles me since my first steps with Android is the optimized use of a custom adapter with different layouts for different orientations. Currently I do end up in cascades of NULL checks and I would like to know if there's a better way.

Consider two different layouts for vertical orientation and horizontal orientation that do contain a different count of widgets.

Here's the vertical layout with one widget located in layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextViewDefault"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the horizontal layout with two widgets located in layout-land:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextViewDefault"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextViewDefault"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextViewDefault"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the custom adapter - an extended SimpleCursorAdapter. Depending on the orientation the description and date objects are null or non-null. In my Android projetcs I do have row layouts with 10ths of objects and these null-checks become really nasty in the code. Is there a better solution? How do you guys work with custom adapters and different layouts for different orientations or sizes?

```
public class TestAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView date;
        private TextView description;
        private TextView name;
    }

    private Context            context;
    private Cursor             cursor;
    private int                layout;
    private SQLiteDatabase     sqliteDatabase;
    private MySQLiteOpenHelper sqliteOpenHelper;

    public Test(final Context context, final int layout, final Cursor cursor, final String[] from, final int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to);

        this.context = context;
        this.cursor = cursor;
        this.layout = layout;

        if (sqliteOpenHelper == null) {
            sqliteOpenHelper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(context);
        }

        if (sqliteOpenHelper != null) {
            if (sqliteDatabase == null) {
                sqliteDatabase = sqliteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View contentView, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View       view = null;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (contentView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);

            if (view != null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
                viewHolder.description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
                viewHolder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
        } else {
            view = contentView;
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) contentView.getTag();
        }

        if (viewHolder != null) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);

            String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Test.DATE));
            String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Test.DESCRIPTION));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Test.NAME));

            if (viewHolder.date != null) {
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(date) && date.length() == 10) {
                    viewHolder.date.setText(Tools.formatDate(date.substring(0, 10)));
                } else {
                    viewHolder.date.setText("");
                }
            }

            if (viewHolder.description != null) viewHolder.description.setText(description);
            if (viewHolder.name != null) viewHolder.name.setText(name);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have different widget count you have to deal with the fact setting different data.
But you can get rid of following null checks:

```
// wouldn't you expect to have a working layout here?
View != null        

// when view != null removed this is obsolete           
viewHolder != null

// the same thing here, you would expect a name here
viewHolder.name != null

// put that under viewHolder.date != null since both are available when one of them is
viewHolder.description.setText(description);
```

Comment: Are you sure? This would mean you would always trust the positive result of "view = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null)", "viewHolder = new ViewHolder()" and "view.findViewById(R.id.name)". I've seen so many NullPointerExceptions during Orientation Changes etc. that only went away when using NULL checks everywhere.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I always did it that way, never checked for null because I didn't see the reason why and I never failed with that (even with very special list view designs). Maybe you're doing something extraordinary which shouldn't be done that why. Recycling should always work well and usually shouldn't fail because of something ordinary like an orientation change...